How to plot monthly purchase data using alluvial plot?
I have monthly data which shows 1. funds received in each month for a population and 2. purchase done for different materials in the form of frequency tables.



month
fund_recd_freq




june
20


july
35


august
45



Now for each month I have purchase data for different materials



month
material_A_purchase




june
23


july
58


august
76






month
material_B_purchase




june
13


july
44


august
58



there are six such materials. I want to know how should I format this data and what code to use so that I can use alluvial type plots as shown in hand drawn diagram below. The frequency counts are not matched with funds received and purchases. The purchase in some cases is not dependent on fund reception (it was done before funds were received). For example, funds are received in September, but purchases were already done in July. Such cases should have different colour if possible.

